# Search giving error for external users

Tags: search, search-results, alternate-access-mapping, https

We are facing issue in SharePoint global search. Below are it's details;

Environment & Configs.:

Version - SharePoint Server 2013

Farm - Total two servers. 1st Server is WFE & APP server. 2nd Server has Database (Sql Server 2012).

Authz - FBA has been configured. Internal users have access through AD accounts, external to FBA.

Access - All HTTP requests from outside server are redirected to HTTPS.

Search Service - Search Service Application has been configured.

AAM - Alternate Access mappings has been done.

Scenario:
From within server: When user accesses application from within server (either windows authz or forms authz) Global search works as expected i.e. search for a term shows results, searching further new terms also shows results.

From client computers: Login to application using Forms Authz. Search for a term (first search) will show results. Try another search with same term or other terms gives error message 'Sorry, something went wrong.'
There are no error messages in browser console or in ULS.

Kindly let know if any further details required.

**update**

Today was able see the 'Show Detail' link which had correlation ID. Based on it checked for logs and found this

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name:
>   String      at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles
>   options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean
>   parseDecimal)      at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value,
>   NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestServiceImpl.ProcessQuery(Stream
>   inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)

Thanks

Comment: With "Sorry, something went wrong." message should be "Technical details" link which will provide you with the correlation id. Try to use PowerShell to search ULS log files using this correlation (even Merge-SPLogfile or Get-SPLogEvent).

Comment: Hi Sergey, have updated the query with logs found. Please check the same

Comment: May I ask you for complete logs? This stack trace is not enough to understand the root cause. You have to collect a set of log entries, including not only High and Critical levels.